# XMLHttpRequest responseText & javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

So I have two pages: **index.php** and **contents.php**. Index.php is doing an XMLHttpRequest to grab a table from contents.php... But when Index.php displays the response.Text, it doesn't run the Javascript originally on contents.php (because it's just displaying the contents, not running the script).

Trying to solve this problem, I simply put the code on index.php rather than contents.php, but for some reason the javascript wont find any elements displayed by the responseText.

(i.e document.getElementById('contents-table').innerHTML = 'asdf';

Comment: example code? You will have to make sure that the code in question is only run *after* the `innerHTML` has been written, but once it has, any `id="..."` elements inside it should certainly be retrievable with `getElementById()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var content = 'asdf',
fragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(content),
parent = document.getElementById("contents-table");

parent.replaceChild(fragment, parent.firstElementChild);
```

considering that there is only one node in the parent node, this should work